# Improving thesis template

Tags: thesis

I've made this template for my master's thesis according to the provided guidelines by the university. The problems this template seems to be fragile a lot of warnings, and the slightest modification will break something. Can you please recommend me how to enhance this template according to these [Guidelines](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k77fyqez4V2VS2rkNqdBc04WKamhriNV/view?usp=sharing)?

```
\documentclass[twoside, 14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,right=10mm,top=20mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm, verbose=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=ieee,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{bera}% optional: just to have a nice mono-spaced font
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}


%\usepackage{microtype}
\addbibresource{~/Documents/Thesis/XXX/references.bib}
\title{
    {XXX}\\
    {\Large University YYY}\\
    {\includegraphics{YYY_logo.jpg}}
}

\author{John doe}
\date{Day Month Year}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\begin{document}

\justifying
\maketitle
\chapter*{\centering{Abstract}}
\subfile{chapters/abstract.tex}

\chapter*{\centering{Dedication}}

\chapter*{\centering{Declaration}}

\chapter*{\centering{Acknowledgement}}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{\centering{Introduction}}
\subfile{chapters/introduction.tex}

\chapter{chapter 1}
\subfile{chapters/chapter_1.tex}
\chapter{chapter 2}
\subfile{chapters/chapter_2.tex}


\chapter*{Conclusion}
\subfile{chapters/conclusion.tex}

\appendix
\subfile{chapters/appendix.tex}
\printbibliography
```

Comment: From a first quick look it does not look bad. The list of packages is reasonably short and most packages look 'normal', and the rest of the document looks fine as well. Could you explain a bit what kinds of warnings are given and which changes break something?

Comment: I agree with Marijn that this is by far not the worst template I have seen. Of course there are many things you could do differently, but some of them may well be matters of taste. I would probably not use `subfiles` unless there is a real need for its features. `\include` or maybe even `\input` are usually enough. `\usepackage{lipsum}` is probably not needed in normal theses (since it just generates dummy text, so I would not load it in a thesis template). ...

Comment: ... In this constellation `\usepackage{url}` is not necessary because the package is already loaded by `biblatex`, but it may help to be explicit (or if you remove `biblatex`). The `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}` is a bit random (but not wrong). I would try to avoid abusing the `\title` command by adding images there, but again sometimes it's easier to make things work with a bit of semantic flexibility. What I find odd is the `\chapter*{\centering{Dedication}}`: In those cases it would be better to redefine `\chapter` accordingly (or to use a new command).

Comment: If you need help with warnings or errors it would help if you could tell us which errors and warnings you get (copy the relevant messages from the `.log` file) and please edit your code so that it reproduces the messages and can be compiled by people who don't have your files (test your example in an empty folder: If you can run it there, it is probably does not depend on files we don't have).